# TZ Database on Debian Stable for Casablanca ignores the permanent change to DST and Adds an offset of 1

Tags: timezone, debian, zoneinfo, tzdata

I am on a Debian Stable 9 (stretch), the newly updated TZ database for Africa/Casablanca Table currently states isdst=0 and an offset from UTC of +01. 
From the DST in Morocco Wiki page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Morocco

It is clear that a permanent offset of UTC +1:00 was added from October 2018 and daylight savings is now permanently observed.

But during Ramadan the offset has been traditionally reset to UTC 00:00. But the TZ database denotes that they add an offset of +01 and isdst is set to 1.

This issue is only applicable to Africa/Casablanca.

It seems to be an issue with Debian Stable. Any advice on fixing this issue is appreciated

zdump -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Casablanca | grep 2019

/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Casablanca  Sun May  5 01:59:59 2019 UT = Sun May  5 02:59:59 2019 +01 isdst=0 gmtoff=3600

/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Casablanca  Sun May  5 02:00:00 2019 UT = Sun May  5 02:00:00 2019 +00 isdst=1 gmtoff=0

/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Casablanca  Sun Jun  9 01:59:59 2019 UT = Sun Jun  9 01:59:59 2019 +00 isdst=1 gmtoff=0

/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Casablanca  Sun Jun  9 02:00:00 2019 UT = Sun Jun  9 03:00:00 2019 +01 isdst=0 gmtoff=3600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [tzdb 2018h release notes](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-December/000053.html) (emphasis mine):

> Changes to future timestamps
>
> Guess that Morocco will continue to fall back just before and  spring
>   forward just after Ramadan, the practice since 2012.  (Thanks to
>   Maamar Abdelkader.)  **This means Morocco will observe  negative DST
>   during Ramadan in main and vanguard formats, and in  rearguard format
>   it stays in the +00 timezone and observes  ordinary DST in all months
>   other than Ramadan.**  As before, extend  this guesswork to the year
>   2037.  As a consequence, Morocco is  scheduled to observe three DST transitions in some Gregorian years  (e.g., 2033) due to the mismatch
>   between the Gregorian and Islamic  calendars.

It was later confirmed that Morocco did indeed adjust its clocks for Ramadan as predicted.  You can read [the tz discussion thread](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2019-April/027861.html), or [the article about it on timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/morocco-changes-clocks-2019.html).

Even the Wikipedia article you cited mentions this:

> ... An exception was made during the month of Ramadan during which clocks reverted to UTC+00:00 (standard time).